# how to change font color with condition in birt scripting

Tags: colors, fonts, scripting, birt

I have a xmldatasource that returns numbers. I need to chnage the font color into red if it is negative or less than zero then green if positive. 
Below solution is not working as it is supposed to. I put it in Onrender and also tried in onPrepare of the datacell itself. (clicked the datacell then script tab). it seems that it is not going inside the IF stament, always executing the else. I figured tat it might be a string type but still when I changed it to string, still wouldn't work.

```
if(this.getValue() < 0) 
    this.getStyle().color = "#F0000"
else this.getStyle().color = "#008040"
```

I also tried

```
if(this.value < 0) 
    this.getStyle().color = "#F0000"
else this.getStyle().color = "#008040"
```

or

```
if(this.value == "-1") 
    this.getStyle().color = "#F0000"
else this.getStyle().color = "#008040"
```

It always executes the else thus always green. What am I missing? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datasets are not yet populated in the "onPrepare" statement, this will work if you put it in "onCreate". However this should run with "onRender" too (it works for me). Be very careful to put the script on the data item, **NOT** on its datacell container.

```
if(this.getValue() < 0) 
    this.getStyle().color = "red"
else this.getStyle().color = "green"
```

By the way, for color coding it is probably a better practice to use "highlights" feature (in Property Editor) rather than scripts.

[image]

Comment: thanks. it worked perfectly in highlights tab. Didn't know this is also applicable for font colors. :)